# create two pages rdlc report for the same dataset

Tags: rdlc

I have a report consist of three tables

I need to add the first table and other texts in first page and reaming of the report in the second page

How to do that please , they all belong to the same dataset ,and the first page will be like a summary

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is work with page breaks. Just put all the field you need for the summary on the report. After that I can imagine that you are going to use a table , a matrix or a list to show the datails. drag the item on the report and right click on it, select the properties. In the genaral tab you will see the page break option, select add page break before. [How to: Set Page Breaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251733%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)